# Browser scroll-bars shows up when setting body and html tags height to 100%

Tags: html, css

I don't get it, why does the browser's vertical scroll-bars appear when running the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>some text</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a live example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlfCv

when I change the `<h1>` element to a `<div>` element, they disappear.

What am I missing? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: It's a goofy margin thing. You could remove the default margins from the h1 and use padding on the body itself, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The h1 element has margin. Margins collapse when two elements are next to each other and form one margin taking the size of the largest value. In this case, you set the body's margin to zero but the h1 margin is still there. Since the h1 element is part of the body, it pushes against the top of the viewport which also pushes the body element down.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1):

Just add this CSS rule:

```
h1 {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Check this [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rDeoq)

The problems occured because the UA stylesheet add a `margin` to some elements (like the `h1` element) by default.